# Form dialog event not catched if ShowDialog() used instead of Show()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dialog

I have created a FormManager class that shows up a custom form named MyFormView. FormManager subscribes to the event that MyFormView throws.

Here the code side that fires the event at MyFormView:

```
public delegate void MyFormClickEventHandler(string name);
public event MyFormClickEventHandler myFormEventHandler;

private void MyFormClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.myFormEventHandler != null)
    {
        this.myFormEventHandler(this.Name.Text);
    }
}
```

FormManager creates the MyFormView dialog and subscribes to the UserControl event:

```
public delegate void MyFormEventHandler(string info);
public static event MyFormEventHandler MyFormEvent;

myFormView = new Window
{
    Title = "my form!",
    Height = 300,
    Width = 980,
    Content = new MyFormView()
};
((MyFormView)myFormView.Content).myFormEventHandler += this.GetDataFromForm;
```

Here to show up the dialog I use:

```
myFormView.Show();
```

The code works fine, the event is fired inside the user control (*MyFormView*) and catched in the actual event handler (*GetDataFromForm*).

The problem is that if I change the last defined line for this one:

```
myFormView.ShowDialog();
```

The problem here is that the event does not get fired because at MyFormClick **myFormEventHandler** is *null*.

What is the difference between *Show()* and *ShowDialog()* that makes *FormManager* to do not subscribe to the event from *myFormview*? Can this be solved?

Comment: Start with [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be much easier to try your code than to guess what you could possible done wrong in code you don't show here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Sinatr. What do you think is missing or not well explained? I will be pleased to add what you suggest :)

Comment: How do you rise event, how subscribe, is there conflicting things: more subscribers, `try/catch { }` (empty catch block), etc. ? Guessing is easy, but it's not really helpful.

Comment: Sinatr, I edited the question with your suggestions.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the event before or after you call ShowDialog?

Comment: I haven't suggest anything, only guess what could be the problem. Reproduce issue with as smallest code as possible and show that **complete** code. Currently it's not possible to follow the logic and find what is wrong.

Comment: Arie, I subscribe to the event before I call ShowDialog, actually in the next line.

Comment: Sinatr then thanks for your no-suggestion. In short I am trying to catch an event fired by a ShowDialog. Using Show instead works. I point the line were it fails, but I do not know why.

Comment: Arie, I was wrong, in my previous comment! Actually that was the problem! I did subscribe after creating the dialog. Thanks a lot! If you want to post the answer I will accept it pleased :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I showed the dialog before subscribing to the event.

Using just Show() it is not a problem, but using ShowDialog() it never subscribes to the event.

Here the code:

```
myFormView = new Window
{
    Title = "my form!",
    Height = 300,
    Width = 980,
    Content = new MyFormView()
};

((MyFormView)myFormView.Content).myFormEventHandler += this.GetDataFromForm;

myFormView.Show();

//or myFormViewShowDialog();
```

Actually Arie is the one that gave the solution in the comments, but did not post it. So I do it for ppl that may have the same issue.